# What is the earliest javascript/jquery-based method to execute javascript ASAP?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to execute a few lines of javascript earlier than the `document.ready` event?

Comment: @jondavidjohn: "earlier than the `document.ready` event" is very precise and this is a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just don't put it in a handler. If you need access to elements, the only way as far as I know is to place the `<script>` element after the elements it needs to access in the document.

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jNCsv/)